# After I declare an object from a class, and try to set a variable to that object inly, why does it say that it does not declare a type?

Tags: arduino

I am writing code for a school project that will be used for a Chromebook charging station with security. The problem I am having now is when I am detecting if a Chromebook is actually in the slot after the user has been assigned one, I am using a rocker switch to simulate this but when I am declaring the pin to the rocker, the arduino verfier comes up with that
"'slot1' does not name a type".
Code is below:

```
    //class
     class Chromebook_slot {
      public:
        String Name = "";
        String RFID_tag = "";
        int rocker = 0;
        boolean chromebook_in = false;
    //class function to check if chromebook is in.
    //if not, redirect already to reassigning so chromebook slot is entered as open and free.
       void set_if_in()
       {
         int momen_1_state = digitalRead(momen_1);
         int momen_2_state = digitalRead(momen_2);

         // the button has been pushed down and the previous process has been completed
         // eg. servos would have been reset if there was a previous user
         if (momen_1_state == HIGH || momen_2_state == HIGH)
         {
           chromebook_in = digitalRead(this->rocker);
          if (chromebook_in == 0)
           {
            re_assigning();
           }

          else
          {
            return;
           }
         }

       }
    };


    //this is now outside the class..

    //class declarations
    Chromebook_slot slot1;
    Chromebook_slot slot2;

    //variables for rocker switches which will act for detecting chromebooks.
    // in my final version, this will replaced by a photoresistor and laser.

    slot1.rocker = 3;
    slot2.rocker = 2;
```

Where the function `re_assigning()` is a separate function declared further in the code and just resets the slot as open for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
slot1.rocker = 3;
slot2.rocker = 2;
```

These are statements that cannot be at the top level of a C++ (or .ino) file.  They need to be inside of a function.  What's happening is the compiler is looking looking at the `slot1` identifier through the lens of potential valid constructions.  It sees an identifier, and about the only thing that could legally exist at this point in the code that starts with an identifier like that is some declaration, e.g. `int a = 7;`, or more abstractly  `some_type some_more_stuff`.  So it expects `slot1` to be a type, which it isn't, hence the message.

If you want an assignment like those to happen early on in an Arduino program, the simplest thing you could do is put them in `setup()`:

```cpp
void setup() {
  slot1.rocker = 3;
  slot2.rocker = 2;
  // ...
}
```

Or, you'd make these part of the `Chromebook_slot`'s constructor, such that they could be given in `slot1` and `slot2`'s declaration:

```cpp
class Chromebook_slot {
public:
    Chromebook_slot(int rocker_init_value) {
      rocker = rocker_init_value;
    }
// ...
```

Or in a maybe less familiar but more proper form, using the constructor's initialization list:

```cpp
class Chromebook_slot {
public:
    Chromebook_slot(int rocker_init_value) 
     : rocker(rocker_init_value) {}
// ...
```

Once you have a constructor for `Chromebook_slot`, your variables can become:

```cpp
Chromebook_slot slot1(3);
Chromebook_slot slot2(2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and now onto the next problem! I found that your first version of class constructor worked better for me to understand because I'm pretty new to classes. Thanks for the fast reply and easy to understand explanation.

Comment: I thought it might be.  The distinction between the two for primitive types like `int` is not great, but keep in mind that you can have things that are possible to initialize/construct but have no assignment operator at all or have no accessible assignment operator.   In that case the decision is made for you that you must use the constructor's initialization list which directly constructs the members.

Comment: Thanks for that! I think I already experienced that when I tried to add in more of variables to the constructor.